# How to build full url of object in django template using `obj.get_absolute_url'?

Tags: django, url, django-templates, sharethis

I am trying to feed "sharethis" `data-url` with the full url (domain + absolute_url) of the object. Currently, I am doing this in django template:

```
<div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons" data-url="http://www.my-domain.com{{program.get_absolute_url}}"></div>
```

However, I want a better method to get this part:

```
http://www.my-domain.com
```

The reason I am looking for this is that the first method does not return a relevant url in development using localhost.
it would return, as an example, this (fictional) url:

```
http://www.my-domain.com/objects/object_slug-object_pk/
```

while I expect this:

```
127.0.0.1.com:8000/objects/object_slug-object_pk/
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [“sites” framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the [sites framwork](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) add the following to the settings.py file.

```
...
SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'django.contrib.sites',
]
```

Then run `python manage.py migrate`
This will create the database table 'django_site' the table has 3 columns id, domain, name.

Set this so that `id = 1, domain='127.0.0.1:8000', name='Test Server'` on your local copy and `id = 1, domain='www.my-domain.com', name='my-domain'` on the live server.

This should then allow you to use the following in your views.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.shortcuts import render

full_url = 'https://%s' % (Site.objects.get_current().domain)


return render(request, 'template.html', {'domain': domain, })
```

in the template use

```
<div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons" data-url="{{domain}}{{program.get_absolute_url}}"></div>
```

Comment: The last part is in the view and would need to be passed to the template.

Comment: while I am passing `obj` to template through view, why should I pass `obj.get_absolute_url()` . I can pass only this part: `Site.objects.get_current().domain`

Comment: `domain = 'https://{}'.format(Site.objects.get_current().domain)`

Comment: and then do this in templeate:
` <div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons" data-url="{{domain}}{{program.get_absolute_url}}"></div> `